# Google, Bing and DuckDuckGo SERPs display a unicode domain in punycode

Tags: google-search, search-results, bing, idn, punycode

A website that I work with ranks very well in all three. It happens to have a unicode domain.

Both regular and image search results pages display the domain as punycode (the `xn--` form) instead of unicode. I can easily imagine how that confuses or even alerts some users.

Is there any way for me to control this?

The browsers display the unicode version in their address bars, just as expected. This proves that the domain is not a concern of [this browser policy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137191/why-does-%e1%a5%90%e1%a5%9e%e1%a5%a8%e1%a5%b2-com-display-as-xn-rgf2a4a2b-com-in-ff-chrome), and therefore shouldn't be falling under similar sanctions (if those exist) with the search engines.

[Searched for *punycode* here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=punycode), the closest I found was [someone dealing with a similar issue on social media previews](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137284/can-i-prevent-social-sharing-on-facebook-from-showing-punycode-for-my-internatio).

**UPDATE** 2023-06-09: Both sitemap and `link rel="canonical"` are using Punycode. Will change them both to use Unicode, see if that makes a difference, and come back here with an update.

**UPDATE** 2023-10-27: It's been almost 5 months since I changed both the sitemap and the canonical links to Unicode, and it made no difference. The image search on all three is still showing the Punycode.